# LibSVM probability estimates changes results

Tags: classification, weka, libsvm

I am new to using LibSVM and I have read a bit about the theory behind probability estimates.

I don't understand why classification results change when changing probability estimates from false to true in the GUI (they sometimes become much better).

How do we decide whether to set probability estimates to true or not?